# Opencart - Getting a product price in the head?

Tags: opencart, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to get the price of a product in the head for an OpenGraph meta tag that requires the price. I can `echo $price` anywhere in the main content area fine but anywhere higher it looks like the variable is not yet set. How can I get the price of the current product in the head?

Answer (score 1):

I would use javascript to assign variable value, invoking the price variable in the header.php would require a ton of work, mixing different modules into one controller would be a mess

Answer (score 0):

You must first define `price` variable in `controller/common/header.php`, and then use it in header.tpl of your theme.